# Best way to iterate trhough all list but one specific value

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, enums, iteration

I have an enum which I can get the values from with Enum.values(), I need to iterate through them and act on all but one value, I am thinking of two ways of evading acting on this values to be excluded. 
First one would be creating a list of the values and removing the one(s) I wouldn't need, like so:

```
List<ObjectEnum> oList= new ArrayList<ObjectEnum>();
Collections.addAll(itinerarySortPriceCriteriaList,ItinerarySortPriceCriteria.values());
oList.remove(ObjectEnum.UNWANTED_ENUM_VALUE);
```

Then iterating through that list and acting on it with a common for each loop.

The other way I am contemplating is iterating through all ObjectEnum values and using an if to skip acting on the ones I wouldn't like to act, like this:

```
for (ObjectEnum o: ObjectEnum.values()) {
    if(!o.equals(ObjectEnum.UNWANTED_ENUM_VALUE)) {
       doThings();
    }
}
```

Do you see any advantages on either of them, which one do you find more readable? Thanks.

This is for a Java6 production 20MM a day requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first code won't work becayse you may not remove anything from a List returned by `Arrays.asList()`. You would need a new ArrayList.

Your second code is fine, but could probably be clearer.

You could use an EnumSet:

```
for (ObjectEnum o : EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(ObjectEnum.UNWANTED_ENUM_VALUE))) {
    ...
}
```

Or a Stream:

```
Arrays.stream(ObjectEnum.values())
      .filter(o -> !o.equals(ObjectEnum.UNWANTED_ENUM_VALUE))
      .forEachOrdered(...);
```

It frankly doesn't matter much, and all solutions are readable, IMO.

The advantage of a List-based or EnumSet-based solution is that you can store the filtered list/set into a field if you need to iterate on this filtered collection several times.

Comment: because you wrote it faster than me +1. I would go for 'stream' solution.

Comment: Nice answer. I have to agree with @Kh.Taheri that the stream option is superior. Having the discriminating code within the .filter() method has more clarity and the stream code is easier to read and quickly understand.

Comment: I believe streams were introduced in Java8, and this project is in Java6, let me add that to the desc.

Answer (score 1):

If your List is not going to change, then better to keep it in enum itself and call everywhere you need:

```
public enum ObjectEnum {    
    A, B, C;

    public static final List<ObjectEnum> ALL_BUT_C =  unmodifiableList(asList(A, B));

}
```

Comment: Nice way to do it, but I can't edit the enum since it comes from another API